# Can't use KeyDown and KeyUp events properly? (Visual C# Windows Form)

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, keydown, keyup

I am having problems in breaking a loop (apparently) with the KeyUp event; Character moves, but then I can't make it stop after releasing the key. Looks like I am doing something wrong.
 What could I change in this code for it to work? Thanks for the help!

```
private void Character_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        XSpeed = 1;
    }

    for (; e.KeyCode == Keys.A;)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Character.Left -= XSpeed;
        if (XSpeed == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void Character_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        XSpeed = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this: `for (; e.KeyCode == Keys.A; Character.Left -= 0)` going to compile?

Comment: Is Character the selected object in the form?

Comment: @Max: Simple, it will take an empty initialization statement. But it would probably be better written as a `while` loop.

Comment: @JeanHominal Ah okay, yeah I think a while loop will be much easier to read.

Comment: By the way, what UI framework are you using?

Comment: @Jean I am sorry, I am not really sure about what an UI framework is (I am a self-taught beginner programmer); but I suppose you would be talking about the Visual Studio designer.

Comment: @user2737037 Yes, it is.

Comment: It is quite fundamental about GUI programming, your for() loop will **never** exit.  Google "windows forms game loop" to get ahead.

Comment: @ViniciusKriegerGranemann: A UI framework is a set of libraries that help you to develop a graphical application. Microsoft provides multiple such frameworks that you can work with C# - Windows Forms, WPF, Windows Store Application. I expect that you made that choice when you created your project in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jean Oh, thank you so much for the explanation. I chose the Windows Form option.

Comment: @ViniciusKriegerGranemann: Consider using WPF instead of Windows Forms if you are doing a Windows application. While it is more complex, it provides much superior data binding, and allows you more easily to decouple UI concerns from the core logic of the application. Also, the Windows Forms Designer makes it too easy to write controls that have absolute positioning everywhere, making it hard for users to usefully resize the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are never going out from the `Character_KeyDown` handler does not terminate. Because of that, your bit of code in the `Character_KeyUp` is never executed.

The root issue that you may not realize is that you only have a single UI thread (at least in all UI frameworks that I know such has been the case), and you are monopolizing it with your `for` loop.

In order to do the right thing, something like WPF's `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, or `DispatcherTimer` can be used. (If you use WPF). If you can tell us which UI framework you are using, we might be able to come up with a satisfactory code sample.

Here is how you might do it with a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) in WPF:

```
// Add that field to your class.
private readonly DispatcherTimer moveLeftTimer;

// In the constructor, add the lines inside:
YourClassName() // This line is a stub - I do not know your class name.
{
    moveLeftTimer = new DispatcherTimer()
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
    };
    moveLeftTimer.Tick += MoveLeft;
}

private void MoveLeft(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Character.Left -= XSpeed;
}

private void Character_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        moveLeftTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

private void Character_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        moveLeftTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

In order to adapt for Windows Forms, use the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class instead of `DispatcherTimer`, and the property is named `Enabled` instead of `IsEnabled`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are doing everything on one thread, in your case it happens to be the Main UI thread. All actions are done sequentially. It does't matter that you have a handler to change `XSpeed = 0`, it's not going to process until the `Character_KeyDown` is done. Put break points in both and you will see the point.
What you need to do is to put your processing on the background thread and release your UI handlers.

`Task.Factory.StartNew` creates a background thread and executes an action you give it.
now if you need to update something that belongs to the UI thread, you gotta do it on the UI thread...

```
private void Character_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
      {
          OnUI(() => XSpeed = 1);
      }

      for (; e.KeyCode == Keys.A;)
      {
          Thread.Sleep(50);
          OnUI(() => Character.Left -= XSpeed);
          if (XSpeed == 0)
          {
              break;
          }
      }});
}

private void Character_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            OnUI(() => XSpeed = 0); 
        }
    }
  }
```

here's a sample for OnUI:

```
private void OnUi (Action action)
{
    if (_dispatchService == null) 
        _dispatchService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDispatchService>();
        //or _dispatchService  = Application.Current.Dispatcher - whatever is suitable

    if (_dispatchService.CheckAccess())
        action.Invoke ();
    else
        _dispatchService.Invoke(action);
 }
```